# Update Apache Felix Bundles during framework start up in Java

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

So I have this code which I call to update bundles in `Apache Felix Framework` during start up, but I only update bundles that I purposely set to level 7 and greater. Whenever this code is executed, the updated bundle is remove from the list and the console hangs. Other times, the updated bundle's status is `ACTIVE` but the console also hangs.

```
Arrays.stream(bundleContext.getBundles())
            .filter((bundle) ->  return bundle.adapt(BundleStartLevel.class).getStartLevel() > 6;
            .forEach((Bundle bundle) -> {
                try {
                    this.logger.log(LOG_DEBUG, "updating : " + bundle.getSymbolicName());
                    if (bundle.getState() == Bundle.ACTIVE) {
                        bundle.stop();
                    }
                    bundle.update();
                    bundle.start(Bundle.ACTIVE);
                } catch (BundleException exception) {
                    this.logger.log(LOG_ERROR, "Bundle update for " + name + " failed.", exception);
                }
            });
```

Is there a proper way to update bundles in `Apache Felix Framework`?

Comment: You don't need to stop a bundle before updating it. Just update it, and OSGi will figure out the necessary state transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description you give and code example it is impossible to tell exactly what goes wrong:

- When is this code exactly invoked?
- You say in your description only bundles that have a startlevel of 7 and greater are updated. I don't see that in the code anywhere. In fact it only updates bundles which have a symbolic name that equals `name`.
- There is no need to invoke `bundle.stop()` and `bundle.start()` at all when doing the update. Furthermore, that logic in this code is flawed: if a bundle was not active before it will become so now.
- If this code is invoked from a `start` method of a `BundleActivator, it might try to update itself, which leads to all kinds of unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code that returns only the bundles with StartLevel greater than 6.

Comment: I think it was a problem in the design. I updated the bundles that are already `ACTIVE` which is unpredictable. I should have just let my level 6 bundle updated all the level 7 bundles before they were started. Thank you for the enlightenment. ^_^ :)

Comment: Updating ACTIVE bundles does *not* lead to unpredictable behaviour. It is perfectly predictable and defined in the OSGi specification.

Comment: I totally agree with Neil. This is not an issue with updating ACTIVE bundles, it must be some other issue (but without a full example that we can look at we can only guess).

Comment: In some cases, whenever I update `ACTIVE` bundles through the code  the bundle gets corrupted, but when I use the console it works fine. I don't know what causes the corruption though, will investigate further with the issue. But it does really occur.

Comment: It would be nice if you could submit some kind of reproducible scenario to the developers of the framework you are using as that definitely should not be happening.